# $_POST values changing or disappearing inside foreach loop

Tags: php, post, foreach

Prior to this `foreach` loop `$_POST['encounterName']` contains a predefined name. Inside the loop its value changes to ".json" so the first string in file_put_contents reads ".json.json". As well `$_POST['basicTrainingSectionSlide']`, `$_POST['basicTrainingContentHeader']`, and 
`$_POST['basicTrainingContentText']` lose their values. After the `foreach` loop, all values go back to normal. What is happening here?

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;

foreach($_POST['Sections'] as $order){

    if(strcmp($order, "Section") == 0){
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t[\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t\t\"Section\",\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t\t\"".$_POST['basicTrainingSectionSlide'][$i]."\"\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t],\n", FILE_APPEND);
        $i++;
    }
    else if(strcmp($order, "Text") == 0){
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t[\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t\t\"Text\",\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t\t\"".$_POST['basicTrainingContentHeader'][$j]."\"\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t\t\"".$_POST['basicTrainingContentText'][$j]."\"\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t],\n", FILE_APPEND);
        $j++;       
    }

}
```

This is what the $_post array contains:

```
array(11) { ["encounterName"]=> string(8) "Violence" ["encounterHint"]=> string(0) "" ["basicTrainingSectionSlide"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "6" } ["basicTrainingContentHeader"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "4" } ["basicTrainingContentText"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "5" } ["contextText_1"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_2"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_3"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_4"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_5"]=> string(0) "" ["submit_form"]=> string(6) "Submit" } array(11) { ["encounterName"]=> string(8) "Violence" ["encounterHint"]=> string(0) "" ["basicTrainingSectionSlide"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "6" } ["basicTrainingContentHeader"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "4" } ["basicTrainingContentText"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "5" } ["submit_form"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

Some added information:
-The form that is filled out sends its post data to a separate php file for processing.
-The `$_POST['Sections']` is sent via this function:

```
function returnValues() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "final.php",
        data:{ Sections: $sectionOrder }, 
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); 
        }
    })
}
```

from a .js file onsubmit of the form tag.

Comment: well, why is it `[$i]` in the first block and `[$j]` in the other? and why are you building json manually? that's just plain dumb... there's `json_encode()` to do all of that for you automatically, and plenty of ways of prett-printing what it does generate

Comment: It has to be a very specific order, I can't just dump the stuff. But yeah, I'll look into square bracketing stuff via that. I need this first.

Comment: Together sections[] size is $i + $j, but they come in random orders depending on the value at $order.

Comment: also look into `fopen` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php and `fwrite`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php as you are opening and closing the file many times which is not needed.

Comment: We can't test this code without some example `$_POST` data.  Can you edit your post to include a `var_dump($_POST)` for us to work with?

Comment: Instead of using `$_POST['encounterName'].".json"` repeatedly, assign it to a variable: `$filename = $_POST['encounterName'].".json";`.

Comment: I can't see any way that the values of these variables could change within the loop, and then change back. Is this really all the code?

Comment: I tried assigning it to a $name variable, but it doesn't make a difference. What I'm trying to do is generate a file based off of a template, so I've just been using the file_put_contents as a line by line so I can find sections better. But again, the structure of that is not the question. I'm going to edit this to show the values going in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$_POST['Sections']` contains something like:

```
array(11) { 
    ["encounterName"]=> string(8) "Violence" 
    ["encounterHint"]=> string(0) ""
    ["basicTrainingSectionSlide"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
        [1]=> string(1) "6" } 
    ["basicTrainingContentHeader"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "2" 
        [1]=> string(1) "4" } 
    ["basicTrainingContentText"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "3" 
        [1]=> string(1) "5" } 
    ["contextText_1"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["contextText_2"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["contextText_3"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["contextText_4"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["contextText_5"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["submit_form"]=> string(6) "Submit" 
}
array(11) { 
    ["encounterName"]=> string(8) "Violence" 
    ["encounterHint"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["basicTrainingSectionSlide"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
        [1]=> string(1) "6" } 
    ["basicTrainingContentHeader"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "2" 
        [1]=> string(1) "4" } 
    ["basicTrainingContentText"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "3" 
        [1]=> string(1) "5" } 
    ["submit_form"]=> string(6) "Submit" 
}
```

I would do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;

foreach($_POST['Sections'] as $order){
    $fn = $order['encounterName'] . ".json";
    $appText = "";
    if(strcmp($order, "Section") == 0){  
        $appText .= "\t\t[\n";
        $appText .= "\t\t\t\"Section\",\n";
        $appText .="\t\t\t\"" . $order['basicTrainingSectionSlide'][$i] . "\"\n";
        $appText .= "\t\t],\n";
        file_put_contents($fn, $appText, FILE_APPEND);
        $i++;
    } elseif(strcmp($order, "Text") == 0){
        $appText .= "\t\t[\n";
        $appText .= "\t\t\t\"Text\",\n";
        $appText .= "\t\t\t\"" . $order['basicTrainingContentHeader'][$j] . "\"\n";
        $appText .= "\t\t\t\"" . $order['basicTrainingContentText'][$j] . "\"\n";
        $appText .= "\t\t],\n";
        file_put_contents($fn, $appText, FILE_APPEND);
        $j++;       
    }
}
```

Since you are in a `foreach` loop and iterating over the array `$_POST['Sections']`, to call the elements of that array, you need to use `$order`. That is how you defined the loop. You kept calling $_POST and those indexes shouldn't exist.

If you were using $_POST, the first occurrence of `encounterName` would be located at `$_POST['Sections'][0]['encounterName']` and would contain the string `Violence`. So, in the loop, `$fn = $order['encounterName'].".json";` should be assigned `Violence.json` as a String.

I am unsure what the `if` statement is looking for. Since `$order` is an Array, not a String, `strcmp()` should return `NULL`. See notes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php#108563). Since both `if` statements would fail, your file would not be appended in either case. Please comment if you want to clarify that.

I tested the following on http://phpfiddle.org/lite :

```
<?php
    $order = array();
    if(strcmp($order, "Section")){
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Fail";
    }
?>
```

I got the following results:

```
E_WARNING : type 2 -- strcmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given -- at line 5
Fail
```

This code is untested.